# AccessDenied application using S3 in AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have hosted a meteor-angular application using S3 in AWS EC2.
Now when I run the Application I am receiving this error message below.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>8WK30J2DDCZRTWXK</RequestId>
    <HostId>6+bSjn5yWA5olpHZb7pcYCBAIlCzPjN8MxxBs3kTuGfuNuNk+CgHDjDeBpXCIjpd5WDVoFnc5Zw=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I have search a lot for a suitable answer and also to understand that might be the issue.

When I run `aws s3 ls` in the terminal I am able to see all the S3 buckets and also in the `IAM Role` I have added the `AmazonS3FullAccess` Permissions policies. But still, the issue remains.

When I go to my bucket permissions it says that `"objects can be public"` and the `public access is not blocked`.

[image]

Here is an example of a Object permission Screenshot.

[image]

Can anyone help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

On your s3 bucket, check the security rules and check if they are available to the public. It looks like you're trying to access it on the web browser if so you'll need to make it public.

I believe you can do this either to the entire bucket or each object the concept should be the same for each.

1. Go to your bucket and select the object using the checkbox.
2. Click on actions and select make public.

Comment: Could you check that when you go to the bucket permissions it says that "objects can be public" and the public access is not blocked?

Comment: I have done that as well, please see the question's attached Image.

Comment: Could you perhaps click on the object that you are trying to access, click on Permissions and send a screenshot?

Comment: Bit odd, if I access https://app.yeslance.com/auth/login directly, I get the error you mentioned, but when I access https://app.yeslance.com, it redirects me to https://app.yeslance.com/auth/login with no issues.

Comment: yes, it is very odd. I don't have any clue what so ever how to solve this problem

Comment: What logic do you have in place to direct a user from the home page to the login page? Wondering if it's how logic related.

Comment: If you open the URL once and give a refresh you will see the error. Somehow the error doesn't appear for the first time but it appears the next time.

Comment: This is why I wonder if it's more related to some sort of logic. It's unusual for the site to be accessible in some instances and not others. Usually, as far as AWS permissions are concerned, it's either always accessible or never accessible.

Comment: might be some cache related issue